# Time complexity of a loop with a nested if-else

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```
// Every iteration of loop counts triplet with 
// first element as arr[i]. 
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) { 

    // Initialize other two elements as corner 
    // elements of subarray arr[j+1..k] 
    int j = i + 1, k = n - 1; 

    // Use Meet in the Middle concept 
    while (j < k) { 

        // If sum of current triplet is more or equal, 
        // move right corner to look for smaller values 
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] >= sum) 
            k--; 

        // Else move left corner 
        else { 

            // This is important. For current i and j, 
            // there are total k-j third elements. 
            for (int x = j + 1; x <= k; x++) 
                cout << arr[i] << ", " << arr[j] 
                     << ", " << arr[x] << endl; 
            j++; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm? Is it O(n*n)??
This is a problem from geekforgeeeks webpage. How do you handle the loop inside the else statement?

Comment: What is the worst case scenario?  What if the sum of those three array elements are  never >= sum?  What if `n == 999999999`?  That's where you should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the code into parts and find the runtime of each.

The outer for loop is O(n).

For every time that loop is called you have a while loop called. So, you'll multiply the complexity of the two loops.

To figure out the runtime of the while loop you have to look at the if and else blocks. If the if block ran every time then the while loop would have an O(n) complexity. If the else part ran every time, then the while loop would have an O(n^2) complexity.

If we are considering worst-case, then you would ignore the if blocks runtime. So, the while loops runtime is O(n^2) and it is called n times through the outer for loop.

Thus, the runtime of it all should be O(n^3).

Comment: I think your answer is correct. I was a little confused because according to this post(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-triplets-with-sum-less-than-or-equal-to-k/) in geekforgeeks.org time complexity is O(n^2)